# storing an attribute's id as a variable and calling it (with additions) later

Tags: jquery, this

I have a series of buttons that each correspond to a a series of images elsewhere in the markup. I'm trying to avoid using the same code a million times with slight changes. Basically I want that when you click on the button id=x it will run code on image id=xT. This is what I've gotten so far, but can't for the life of me get the syntax correct. Am I missing something obvious? Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var slider = ("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "T"); 
        $(slider).slideDown(750);
    });
});
```

EDIT:

For instance, the below is working code, the question is how to run the variable with the id of whatever the clicked element is plus the T at the end to signify the image to slideDown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#current").click(function(){
        var slider = $("#currentT"); 
        slider.slideDown(750);
    });
});
```

Comment: Whatever you click. Not necessarily a button per say, but anything on the page. As long as there is a corresponding image to slide, when you click x, xT should slide.

Answer (score 1):

Your first selector doesn't really make sense. If you're looking for buttons, select the buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var slider = "#" + this.id + "T";
        $(slider).slideDown(750);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can do this perfectly, try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':button').click(function(){
        var slider = ("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "T"); 
        $(slider).slideDown(750);
    });
});
```